# How to get the value of 'reports' array from suct type of GA array?

Tags: arrays, google-analytics

How can I get the value of the `reports` array from suct type of a GA array. This is the array that I got when I made a request to google analytics.

```
Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsResponse Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => reports
    [reportsType:protected] => Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Report
    [reportsDataType:protected] => array
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [reports] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [columnHeader] => Array
                                (
                                    [dimensions] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => ga:userGender
                                            [1] => ga:browser
                                            [2] => ga:userAgeBracket
                                        )

                                    [metricHeader] => Array
                                        (
                                            [metricHeaderEntries] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Pageviews
                                                            [type] => INTEGER
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Users
                                                            [type] => INTEGER
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )
```

Comment: What are you exactly asking? What have you tried so far? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Comment: What do you mean by `suct type`? Do you mean `such type`?